# How to generate one value each minute out of irregular data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have values that are mesured **event-related**. So there are not the same amount of data every Minute. To be able to better handle this data I aim to only **take the first row of values every Minute**.

The time of the data I import from a csv looks like this:

**time**

11.11.2011 11:11

11.11.2011 11:11

11.11.2011 11:11

11.11.2011 11:12

11.11.2011 11:12

11.11.2011 11:13

The other values are Temperatures.
One main problem ist to import the time in the right format.
I tried to solve this with the help of this comunity like this:

```
with open('my_file.csv','r') as file:
for line in file:
    try:
        time = line.split(';')[0] #splits the line at the comma and takes the first bit
        time = dt.datetime.strptime(time, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
        print(time)
    except:
        pass
```

then I importet the columns of the temperatures and joind them like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", sep=';', encoding='latin-1')

df=df[["time", "T1", "T2", "DT1", "DT2"]]
```

when I printed the dtypes of my data the time was datetime64[ns] and the others where objects.

I tried different options of groupby and resample. Like the following:

```
df=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'time', freq='1min')])
df.resample('M')
```

One main problem that was stated in the error messages was that the datatype of the time was not appropriate for grouping,... because it is not an DatetimeIndex.
So I tried to convert the dates to a DatetimeIndex like this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(daten["time"].index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but then I reseaved a Nummeration of the Index starting with 1970-01-01 so I am not quite shure if this conversion is possible with irregular data.

Without this conversion I also get the message `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000026938A74850>`

When I then try to call my dataframe the message shows and when saving it to csv like this:

```
df.to_csv('04_01_DTempminuten.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8',  sep =';', date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I receive either the same message or only one line with a Dezimalnumber instead of the time.

Does anyone have an idear how to deal with this irregular data to get one line of values each minute?

Thank you for reading my question. I am really thankful for any Idears.

Comment: Can share your file with sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data I can only show how I do it with irregular time series, which I think is your case. I work with price data which comes at irregular time intervals. So if you need to sample taking the first minute value you can use resample with for a specific interval using ohlc aggregation function, that will give you four columns for each sample interval.

- open: first value in the interval
- high: highest
- low: lowest value
- close: last value

In your case the sampling interval would 1 minute ('T')

In the following example I'm using one second ('S') as resampling frequency, to resample **ask** column (your temperature column):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_tick_data.csv')
df['date_time']  = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
df.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)

df.head(6)
```

[image]

```
df['ask'].resample('S').ohlc()
```

[image]

This is not solving your date issue, which is a prerequisite for this part because the data set needs to be indexed by date. If you can provide sample data maybe I can help you with that part either.

Comment: The pd.to_datetime request works well thanks for the tipp, with a formater and now the type is datetime64[ns].
Resample could be a great way to make regular data out of my irregular ones.
As you stated it is important to have a close look to the sample data. By looking closer at them I found out that part of the problem is that the coma seperator is an "," not like it is common an ".". So next I will be trying to replace these in the dataframe to be able to convert the datetype from object to float and then applie the resample methode.
Thanks for your Help!